# React: How to get New Date once with the event occurs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to get New Date the same time when an event occurs. Currently, date shows second by second, and when I user `constructor` I can't get the time when the event occurs.

src/components/AnimationItem.js

```
export default class AnimationItem extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { items } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="animation">
        <img
          src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets/img/animation-${
            items[0].id
          }.gif?${new Date().getTime()}`}
          alt=""
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: store a variable inside render and use it? not sure why you want to do that btw

Comment: @Sagivb.g That will have the same effect as the current code.

Comment: then i'm afraid i don't understand your issue.

Answer (score 0):

By event, I believe you are referring to a periodical event that happens second by second.

That actually doesn't matter because it can be any type of event. The thing that matters here is to use React state which always triggers `render()` when it updates itself.

Try something like this: (Assuming periodical event)

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    datestamp: new Date().getTime()
  };
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.startTimer();  // start timer upon component creation
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  this.stopTimer();   // clear timer upon component destruction
}

startTimer() {
  this.timer = setInterval(() => {
    this.setState({
      datestamp: new Date().getTime()
    });
  }, 1000);
}

stopTimer() {
  clearInterval(this.timer);
}

render() {
  const { items } = this.props;
  return (
    <div className="animation">
      <img
        src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets/img/animation-${
          items[0].id
        }.gif?${this.state.datestamp}`} // Assign state for the timestamp here
        alt=""
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```